# iOS Core Data NSFetchRequest groupby relationship object

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have 2 entities : Post & Category , Post entity has relationship to one with Category, each Post has One Category.

```
Post           Category
----           --------
postId         categoryId
title          title
slug           slug
category ----> posts
```

what i need here is NSFetchRequest to fetch posts by date, then to groupBy Category.

so result would be something like:

```
Category1:
  - Post 1
  - Post 2
```

```
Category 2:
 - Post 3
 - Post 4
```

i've tried :

```
[_fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"category.categoryId", nil]];
```

and :

```
[_fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"category", nil]];
```

with no success. Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this:

```
//context is the NSManagedObjectContext
NSEntityDescription* post = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Post"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSAttributeDescription* catDesc = [post.attributesByName objectForKey:@"category"];
[_fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:catDesc, nil]];
```

Comment: i've tried that , giving me crash:

    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions ((<NSAttributeDescription: 0x8fb0950>), name __af_resourceIdentifier, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Post, renamingIdentifier __af_resourceIdentifier, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null) is not in the GROUP BY)

Comment: im using AFIncrementalStore, which inserts the attribute mentioned above `__af_resourceIdentifier` which cause the crash

Comment: Sorry just read your question more carefully, maybe what you want here is not a groupby but an order by, i.e. you sort your post by categoryId and you can then iterate through them to break it down into groups.

The easiest way to do this that I can think of write now is add a categoryId field in the Post Entity and set the sortDescriptors accordingly.